# someone sent me this cipher. what does it say?

Tags: cipher

someone sent me this cipher by email."gnkx bzud skoo xgzfg dzxh, tjg kg kx tkbbdf gnzy hlj uzh iyls. ky gnkx bzud hlj ezy nzrd gdzux. hlj skoo td fzekyb lgndfx. gnd ulfd hlj vkyc gnd ulfd hlj iyls."I don't know what is says or how to crack it. people have said that they solved it, but no one will well me. (FYI the person that emailed me was james.hermenegild@gmail.com)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about where this comes from? I ask because the decrypted plaintext makes me wonder whether it comes from some sort of competition, and because etiquette around here is that we credit our sources. Obviously the latter doesn't really matter if it's just a friend of yours having fun, but that's not the way it looks...

Comment: Your friend must be up to something *big*.

Comment: It was not from a friend(no idea who it's from/for). Why, what does it say?

Answer (score 9):

Kh epcl: Baqg tcaq lmet lboev smhc, ucm qh vu puvkxz mpoa acg ber sgwk. Vp htxw zifm mbw qmc ltdx bsnog. Kdy pqet pr tooxrz wmpseu. Htt qhzx gch hwzs xam fwfr acg zrhe. Bb'g n uwyepx anjggkhgimhv vqdugf mch jcbxevwd.odq vig jfrcy ui tkmmbm rcguac.

(The above is unlikely to be heplful to the OP as it stands, though experienced PSE denizens may well be able to figure it out without too much pain. I will decrypt it, if appropriate, once it's clearer where the question is from. The main purpose of this answer is to discourage others from leaping in where it would be better to wait until we know what's going on.)

Comment: Pwot eixkwopj­­

Comment: Vvmco rwn! Qh noieth fm...

Comment: +1 for the text in parenthesis, in particular.